# Can IoT devices share their own capability/resources with another device?

Tags: hardware, aws-iot, microsoft-windows-iot, software, google-iot-core

Hello IoT Stack community !

I am sort of a beginner at IoT and looking for some guidance and help

I am struggling to wrap my head around the following concept;

> Is it possible for IoT Device to share it's own resource (like e.g
> temp sensing or camera view)  with another device (the other one may
> or may not be an IoT device itself)

how would a scheme like this operate?

is there any relevant literature on this? anything that is beginner friendly ?

Any help I can get in this regard would be duly appreciated!

Comment: Welcom to the site!  Your two questions are really quite different; it would consequently be better to split the question in two, focusing on one of the two questions in this post.  Also, it would be best to [edit] to clarify your exact question: for instance, many IoT devices are custom made with a combination of generic sensors and boards (for example, rpis, esp, etc.), in which case it is clearly possible to share data between devices; thus I assume you are referring to comercial devices; and to answer the question we'll need to know which one(s) in particular you are referring to. [...]

Comment: [...] and for the second question, you will have to give us a good deal more detail on your project and what you mean by "simulate an IoT environment" before it will be answerable; everything from a diagram made with pen and paper to a full-blown 3d model of a house with sensors, controls, editable parameters, etc., could be considered a simulated IoT environment.  Please [edit] it down to one question and clarify your exact requirements for your project.  Thanks!

Comment: @anonymous2 thanks ! i think i should split it into two - btw, how should i go about it ? should i publish two separate questions ? in which case - can you tell me what would be the appropriate tags for each question  ?

Comment: Remove one of the two questions from this post, and post it as a separate question :D  As far as tags are concerned, it will depend on the details you add; try to select tags which match your precise subject as well as possible.  Glad to help, and once again, welcome to the site!  Btw, you can earn a second badge by taking the [tour], and the [help] is a great resource for generic questions about how this site works!

Comment: your first question is not really related to IoT ..... your second question belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jsotola, thanks for pointing out that stack exchange. I did not even know that existed !

Comment: @anonymous2 I have updated the question and split it into two .. would appreciate if you can direct some audience to my questions